# Group on sum of distinct values in Tableau

Tags: distinct, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau 8.3 and i'm trying to find out how to group on each of the values that I find after making a "count of distinct values".

To illustrate the case I have made a fictive dataset which includes 58 rows (buys), 7 different IDs (customers) and 5 different products. Then I have made a count distinct to find out how many of the 5 different products each ID have bought. It looks like this.

`ID1 = 4`
`ID2 = 4`
`ID3 = 5`
`ID4 = 4`
`ID5 = 3`
`ID6 = 4`
`ID7 = 2`

Now I want to turn the view around and find out how many of the IDs who have bought X different products. It should ultimately look like this.

`2 = 1`
`3 = 1`
`4 = 4`
`5 = 1`

Hope to find a solution by posting here! Thank you,

Mikael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update to Tableau 9.0 to achieve that (in a fast way).

You can create a calculated field named #of products:

```
{ FIXED [id_customer] : COUNTD([id_product]) }
```

Then you can cross the [# of products] with COUNTD(id_customer) to get what you want.

In older versions of Tableau you need to create a new table in a proper format (1 line per customer with the aggregations) and connect to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't know when 9.0 will be available to me, but until then I will use your other mentioned solution. It works in a small scale.